# Convert List of List of Object to a map - using lambdas in java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have object structure like below:

```
Order {
    int code;
    int id;
    List<Item>;
}

Item {
     int code;
     int quantity;
     List<Suborder>;
}

Suborder {
    int code;
    int quantity;
}
```

I have an object of O and I want a map from code to B. Whats the correct way to do this?

What I tried :

1 - Not working

```
order.getOrderItems().stream().flatMap(l -> l.getOrderItemSuborder().stream()).collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.getCode() , Function.identity())); // x.getCode() seems to be not available here  :(
```

2 - Working

```
order.getOrderItems().forEach(x -> x.getOrderItemSuborder().forEach(y -> suborderMap.put(y.getCode(),y)));
```

I am not sure if #2 is right way to do it.

How can i make #1 working?

P.S. : Starting with lambdas, might be a stupid question, but i don't know that if it is :p

Comment: Your "example" code for O, A, B is very confusing. Consider putting "real" classes there, at least *full types*. I have no idea what you mean by "a; b; "x; or y". And then: make sure to properly format your source code input; even when having it in a numbered list!

Comment: thanks for valuable feedback. i ll keep that in mind for future questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand I think you need something like this

```
O order;
order.getAList().stream()
      .flatMap(a -> a.getBList().stream())
      .collect(toMap(b -> b.getCode(), b -> b));
```

When you did the first try, what you needed was `b -> b`, I think you missed out that part of the collect map in the lambda

Comment: thanks. this works. but then, what i tried was exactly the same ( i had l,x instead of a,b). Its the stupid eclipse that wasn't listing the methods of the class B when i tried x. (dot operator).

Comment: in the collect you only had `toMap(x-> x.getCode(), x)` what you needed was `toMap(x -> x.getCode(), x -> x)` you missed the second part out

Comment: i am sorry about that but it was there in the code, missed it while pasting here.  Still eclipse couldn't list the methods after dot operator.
does your eclipse show that?

Comment: I haven't used eclipse in a few years, I am using intellij

Comment: cool. such issues keep occurring, i might have to switch as well.

Comment: I like it very much, I switched about 3 years ago and I haven't looked back