# Java 8 convert List to Lookup Map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, lookup, collectors

I have a list of Station, in each Station there is a list of radios. I need to create a lookup Map of radio to Station. I know how to use Java 8 stream forEach to do it:

```
stationList.stream().forEach(station -> {
    Iterator<Long> it = station.getRadioList().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        radioToStationMap.put(it.next(), station);
    }
});
```

But I believe there should be more concise way like using `Collectors.mapping()`.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that no radio maps to more than one station?

Comment: `stationList.stream().forEach(station -> station.getRadioList().stream().forEach(rl -> radioToStationMap.put(rl, station)))` not good enough for you?

Comment: @ZhenyaM It's better to use stream operations and a `collect` than to use `forEach` to write to a mutable list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert List of List of Object to a map - using lambdas in java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213731/convert-list-of-list-of-object-to-a-map-using-lambdas-in-java-8)

Comment: I’m pretty sure the most “concise way” is not to use lambdas or Streams at all.

Comment: @EricWilson, which part is _very convoluted_? I understood the answer in a single read. I do agree it might require a bit more details, but other than that - it is a good one.

Answer (score 10):

This should work and you don't need third parties.

```
stationList.stream()
    .map(s -> s.getRadioList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(b -> b, b -> s)))
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on the question, considering the entities `Radio` and `Station` to be defined as:

```
@lombok.Getter
class Radio {
    ...attributes with corresponding 'equals' and 'hashcode'
}

@lombok.Getter
class Station {
    List<Radio> radios;
    ... other attributes
}
```

One can create a lookup map from a `List<Station>` as an input using a utility such as:

```
private Map<Radio, Station> createRadioToStationMap(final List<Station> stations) {
    return stations.stream()
            // create entries with each radio and station
            .flatMap(station -> station.getRadios().stream()
                    .map(radio -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(radio, station)))
            // collect these entries to a Map assuming unique keys
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                    AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue));
}
```

---

Slightly different from this behaviour, if for same(equal) `Radio` element across multiple `Station`s, one wants to group all such stations, it can be achieved using `groupingBy` instead of `toMap` such as :

```
public Map<Radio, List<Station>> createRadioToStationGrouping(final List<Station> stations) {
    return stations.stream()
            .flatMap(station -> station.getRadios().stream()
                    .map(radio -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(radio, station)))
            // grouping the stations of which each radio is a part of
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                    Collectors.mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using a third-party library, there is the method `groupByEach` from [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
Multimap<Radio, Station> multimap = 
    Iterate.groupByEach(stationList, Station::getRadioList);
```

This can also be written using Java 8 Streams with the `Collectors2` utility from Eclipse Collections:

```
Multimap<Radio, Station> multimap =
        stationList.stream().collect(
                Collectors2.groupByEach(
                        Station::getRadioList,
                        Multimaps.mutable.list::empty));
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do it in more concise way using Collectors, as compared to mixed solution like

```
    stationList.stream().forEach(station -> {
        for ( Long radio : station.getRadioList() ) {
            radioToStationMap.put(radio, station);
        }
    });
```

or

```
    stationList.forEach(station -> {
        station.getRadioList().forEach(radio -> {
            radioToStationMap.put(radio, station);
        });
    });
```

(you can call .forEach directly on collections, don't need to go through `.stream()`)

Shortest fully 'functional' solution I was able to come up with would be something like

```
 stationList.stream().flatMap(
     station -> station.getRadioList().stream().map(radio -> new Pair<>(radio, station)))
 .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getKey(), p -> p.getValue()));
```

using any of the Pair classes available in third party libraries. Java 8 is very verbose for simple operations, compared to dialects like Xtend or Groovy.

Comment: If you have duplicates in `radio`, you'll get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key`. To prevent it you can add merger like  `Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue, (station, station2) -> station2)` in your solution

Comment: If there are duplicates, Multimap should be probably used instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
radioToStationMap = StreamEx.of(stationList)
        .flatMapToEntry(s -> StreamEx.of(s.getRadioList()).mapToEntry(r -> s).toMap())
        .toMap();
```

By [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

Answer (score 0):

Just as in Artur Biesiadowski answer i think you must create a list of pair's and then group them, at least if you want to cater for the case that the radios are not unique per station.

In C# you have practical anonymous classes one can use for this, but in Java you would have to define at least the interface of the Pair class

```
interface Radio{ }
interface Station {
    List<Radio> getRadioList();
}
interface RadioStation{
    Station station();
    Radio radio();
}

List<Station> stations = List.of();

Map<Radio,List<Station>> result= stations
   .stream()
   .flatMap( s-> s.getRadioList().stream().map( r->new RadioStation() {
        @Override
        public Station station() {
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        public Radio radio() {
            return r;
        }
    }  )).collect(groupingBy(RadioStation::radio, mapping(RadioStation::stations, toUnmodifiableList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can save the intermediate step of collectiong to a Map by transforming directly to a Stream of [SimpleEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html), for example:

```
Map<Long, Station> result = stationList.stream()
                .flatMap(station -> station.getRadioList().stream().map(radio -> new SimpleEntry<>(radio, station)))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(SimpleEntry::getKey, SimpleEntry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without Streams, of course, probably making it a bit more readable.

```
Map<Radio, Station> LOOK_UP = new HashMap<>();
List<Station> stations = ...


stations.forEach(station -> {
    station.getRadios().forEach(radio -> {
         LOOK_UP.put(radio, station);
    });
});
```

This is not very different than a plain loop with:

```
for (Station station : stations) {
     for (Radio radio : station.getRadios()) {
          LOOK_UP.put(radio, station);
     }
}
```

The obvious problem here is that `LOOK_UP::put` will always replace the value for a certain key, hiding the fact that you ever had duplicates. For example:

```
[StationA = {RadioA, RadioB}]
[StationB = {RadioB}]
```

When you search for `RadioB` - what should you get as a result?

If you could have such a scenario, the obvious thing is to change the `LOOK-UP` definition and use `Map::merge`:

```
    Map<Radio, List<Station>> LOOK_UP = new HashMap<>();
    List<Station> stations = new ArrayList<>();

    stations.forEach(station -> {
        station.getRadios().forEach(radio -> {
            LOOK_UP.merge(radio,
                          Collections.singletonList(station),
                          (left, right) -> {
                              List<Station> merged = new ArrayList<>(left);
                              merged.addAll(right);
                              return merged;
                          });
        });
    });
```

Another possibility is to throw an Exception when there are these kid of mappings:

```
stations.forEach(station -> {
       station.getRadios().forEach(radio -> {
            LOOK_UP.merge(radio, station, (left, right) -> {
                 throw new RuntimeException("Duplicate Radio");
            });
       });
 });
```

The problem with this last snippet, is that you can't really log the `radio` that is to be blamed for non-uniqueness. `left` and `right` are `Stations`s. If you want that too, you will need to use a *merger* that does not rely on `Map::merge` internally, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44415975/1059372).

So you can see, that it all depends on how and what exactly you need to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be a little different answer, but we can do it using flatMapping collector provided with Java9.

this is your station class -

```
class Station {
public List<String> getRadioList() {
    return radioList;
}

private List<String> radioList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And the list of stations you want to map -

```
        List<Station> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Below is the code that will let you map it using flatMapping collector.

```
list.stream().collect(Collectors.flatMapping(station ->
                    station.getRadioList().stream()
                            .map(radio ->Map.entry( radio, station)),
            Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue), (radio, radio2) -> radio2)));
```

1. We will convert them to Map.Entry
2. We will collect all of them together with flatmapping collector

If you don't want to use flatMapping, you can actually first use FlatMap and then collect, it will be more readable.

```
list.stream().flatMap(station -> station.getRadioList().stream().map(s -> Map.entry(s, station)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (radio, radio2) -> radio2)));
```