# Is Java’s Collectors.toSet() guaranteed to permit nulls?

Tags: java, java-8, null, java-stream

The [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) interface makes no promises on whether implementations permit `null` elements. Each implementation is supposed to declare this in its documentation.

[`Collectors.toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--) promises to return an implementation of `Set` but explicitly makes “no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the `Set` returned”. Null-safety is not mentioned.

The current implementation of `Collectors.toSet()` in OpenJDK always uses `HashSet`, which permits null elements, but this could change in the future and other implementations may do differently.

If a `Set` implementation prohibits `null` elements, it throws `NullPointerException` at various times, in particular during an attempt to [`add(null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#add-E-). It would seem that if `Collectors.toSet()` decided to use a null-intolerant `Set` implementation, calling [`stream.collect(Collectors.toSet())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) on a `Stream stream` would throw. The specification of `collect` does not list any exceptions, nor does the specification of any of the [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) methods. This could suggest that the `collect` call permits nulls within `stream`, but on the other hand it’s not clear whether this actually means much at all, as `NullPointerException` is an unchecked exception and doesn’t strictly have to be listed.

Is this specified more clearly anywhere else? In particular, is the following code guaranteed not to throw? Is it guaranteed to return `true`?

```
import java.util.stream.*;

class Test {
    public static boolean setContainsNull() {
        return Stream.of("A", "list", "of", null, "strings")
                     .collect(Collectors.toSet())
                     .contains(null);
    }
}
```

If not, then I assume we should always ensure a stream contains no nulls before using `Collectors.toSet()` or be ready to handle `NullPointerException`. (Is this exception alone enough though?) Alternatively, when this is unacceptable or hard, we can request a specific set implementation using code like `Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)`.

**Edit:** there is an [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081063/how-should-we-manage-jdk8-stream-for-null-values) that sounds superficially similar, and this question got closed as a supposed duplicate of that. However, the linked question does not address `Collectors.toSet()` at all. Moreover, the answers to that question form the *underlying assumptions* of my question. That question asks: are nulls allowed in streams? Yes. **But what happens when a (perfectly allowed) stream that contains nulls gets collected via a standard collector?**

Comment: It's not mentioned, but I think it would be terribly bad form if it didn't allow nulls, and didn't say anything about that.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi The question you linked has no relation to the standard collectors, which is what I’m asking about. It asks whether streams can contain nulls (they do, and my question takes this for granted) and whether there is any magic that lets explicitly null-intolerant code applied to a stream that contains nulls to avoid NPE (there isn’t). `collect(Collectors.toSet())` isn’t explicitly null-intolerant code—or if you will, I’m exactly asking whether it is.

Comment: Since it doesn’t specify, I would not assume either way.  If I knew null values were a possibility, I would always use `toCollection(HashSet::new)`, to be completely safe.

Answer (score 7):

There is a difference between deliberately unspecified behaviors, like “type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety” and underspecified behavior, like the `null` support.

Whenever a behavior is underspecified, the actual behavior of the reference implementation tends to become the matter of fact that can’t be changed later, even if counteracting the original intention, due to compatibility constraints, or at least it can’t be changed without a strong reason.

Note that while the reserved right to return a truly immutable or non-serializable `Set` was not used, simply because no such type existed upon the Java 8 release, enforcing a non-`null` behavior was possible even without the existence of an adequate hash map type, just like `groupingBy` forbids `null` keys, though underspecified as well.

Note further that while the `groupingBy` collector deliberately rejects `null` keys in its implemen­tation code, `toMap` is a good example of how actual behavior becomes part of the contract. In Java 8, `toMap` allows `null` keys but rejects `null` values, simply because it invokes `Map.merge` which has that behavior. [It seems, this wasn’t an intended behavior in the first place.](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8148463)  Now, in Java 9, the `toMap` collector without a merge function doesn’t use `Map.merge` anymore ([JDK-8040892](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8040892), see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44415975/2711488)), but deliberately rejects `null` values in the collector code, to be behavioral compatible with the previous version. Simply because it was never said that the `null` behavior is intentionally unspecified.

So, `Collectors.toSet()` (and likewise `Collectors.toList()`) allow `null` values for two major Java versions now and there’s no specification saying that you must not take this for granted, so you can be quite sure that this won’t change in the future.

Comment: +1 Btw, the new Java 10 `toUnmodifiable` collectors won't allow null values. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184690