# Java8 toMap exception message confusing

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

Got this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key 50
```

I looked over every map that is using that code, and there is no such key
It took me a while but I found the problem but it is confusing and very problematic to understand don't know why they did it like this

this is my code:

```
    List<Person> listOfPeople = new LinkedList<Person>();

    Map<String, Integer> myMap = listOfPeople
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                        Person::getNameInString,
                                        Person::getAgeInInt
                                )
                );
```

My map is String to Integer, so were did 50 came from???

Comment: Q and A immediately? Are you trying to achieve some badges?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn it's quite alright to ask a question and answer it yourself immediately. If the question and answer are good, it's even recommended.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn if you look on the "Ask question" page, there is a check box to allow you to answer at the same time as posting the question.

Comment: Really? I think it's some kind of abusing

Comment: While it's against no rules (and even encouraged) to answer your own questions you should at least look if the exact same question has been asked before :)

Comment: Answer yourself is same as answer immediately?

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking

Comment: FYI: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8179323

Answer (score 3):

The Answer is that:
I took me some digging finding the relevant input causing this problem.

It turns out that I had two people with the same name,
So why not print:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key "Ohad Edelstein"
```

For example.

were did they get 50?!?!
50 is the age, of the first "Ohad Edelstein"!

How did I get that?
I looked in the documentation and found this method:

```
private static <T> BinaryOperator<T> throwingMerger() {
    return (u,v) -> { throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u)); };
}
```

What is u and v?
This is the method calling it in **HashMap**

```
remappingFunction.apply(old.value, value)
```

What is the point of printing the value?!?! why not write something like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key "Ohad Edelstein", first value 50 second value 35
```

Any way, hope it will prevent others from at least part of the frustration

FYI, to handle the exception issue - if you are fine with it, you can take a look at this answer:
[Ignore duplicates when producing map using streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32312876/ignore-duplicates-when-producing-map-using-streams)

Comment: This could actually be a tiny bug caused by confusing `(u, v)` to be `(k, v)` which is usually used for key/value. It certainly has nothing to do with key, as there's only access to old and new **value**.

Comment: @Kayaman you can still get the key, but you have to do it differently, not via `toMap` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407112/how-to-get-the-key-in-collectors-tomap-merge-function

Comment: @Eugene sure, but from inside `Collectors.throwingMerger()` you don't have much chance. Looks like they removed the whole method in JDK 9 and fixed the exception to show the key as well as both values.

Comment: @Kayaman that is correct, java-9 changed that entirely